# "Unsuccess" versus "failure"

Tags: word-choice, differences, nouns

Are there differences in usage between *[unsuccess](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unsuccess)* and *failure*?

Is *failure* harsher to hear than *unsuccess*? In other words, is *unsuccess* a euphemism of *failure*?

Comment: Do you mean unsuccessful? Because 'unsuccess' isn't a word...

Comment: @Mark: I found it in an online dictionary http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unsuccess. The link was removed by another user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By most people's definition, [unsuccess](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unsuccess) is not a word. It's easy to understand even if you've never seen it before, so a few people are bound to use it. But we're talking about *very* few people...

[image]

Most nouns don't have an unambiguous "opposite" that we can invoke with a negating prefix, and for those that do, we usually use the *non-* prefix anyway.

Offhand the only nouns I can think of that we negate using *un-* are already-inflected "abstract" forms such as *unconsciousness, unhelpfulness, unwillingness*. But note that *unsuccessfulness* is [even less common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unsuccess,unsuccessfulness&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) than *unsuccess* - probably because it's just too much of a mouthful.

EDIT: Thanks to @Unreason (who with that name has a vested interest in the matter!) for pointing out that there are a handful of *un[noun]* negations. Of which **unrest** is universally accepted, as to a lesser extent are *unconcern, unreason, unbelief*, etc. But in such cases the stem word usually also functions as a verb. The exception being *unbelief*, which I believe to be a pathological formulation primarily associated with poetic and pseudo-academic contexts (the standard negated form is *disbelief*).

Comment: What kinds of people are those few people using it? less uneducated, more sophisticated, or ...?

Comment: Unsuccess does sound very ugly, and failure is much more common, however if you examine the results of ngram search you will see that the comparison looks like that because failure is very common (11M results) and unsuccess is rare (20k results). However 20k is comparable to for example 'litotes' (no relation, just a rarely used, technical word; http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unsuccess%2Clitotes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3 ). My point and question is: why do say 'by most people's definition it is not a word'?

Comment: @Tim: Taking into account my additional point about not using *un-* to negate nouns, I think it's unlikely many of the (relatively few) native speakers who use *unsuccess* do so out of ignorance. No matter how badly-educated a person is, they can hardly avoid being unconsciously aware of such a basic rule. I imagine most usages will either be done for poetic/whimsical effect, or simply because the writer is a non-native speaker with limited competence in English.

Comment: @Unreason: It's *not a word* because most native speakers think it isn't. IMHO, the reason they think this is firstly because they [almost] never see/hear it, and secondly because **we don't normally negate nouns by using the "un-" prefix**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, do most native speakers think that litotes is a word? (I think that here more important is that to most native speakers "unsuccess" *does not sound like a word* and for that your second argument is **much** more important and valid).

Comment: @Unreason: I feel you're just being contentious. I've just explained **in bold type** exactly why *unsuccess does not sound like a word*. It violates a well-observed "rule" governing how we normally negate nouns. Even though most speakers aren't consciously aware of that rule, it's what causes them to say *unsuccess* sounds "ugly". With *litotes*, people who don't know the word would normally just say they don't know it - they wouldn't have any predisposition to say it doesn't sound like a valid word at all.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, my apologies, it was not my intention to offend nor to amplify noise. Here are some more nouns that do not follow the pattern in your answer: unbelief, unconcern, unrest (taken from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/un- )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1603/discussion-between-fumblefingers-and-unreason)

Comment: For me, `unsuccess` sounds very *Orwellian*.

Answer (score 6):

[Nobody uses the word "unsuccess"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unsuccess,failure&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). Its meaning is obvious, so you can use it as a euphemism for failure, but your readers will find it odd.

Comment: I found it in an online dictionary http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unsuccess. Also the graph doesn't show it clearly. If you click "unsuccess" below, there are books using it.

Comment: Ermm... In what sense would *unsuccess* be a "euphemism"? Do you work in an office where the boss insists every worker must have *Failure is a dirty word* tattooed on their forehead?

Comment: It's a euphemism in the sense that failure is negative while success is positive, and unsuccess sounds more success-y than "failure". In the same way that when something is "not good" that isn't as strong a statement as "it's bad".

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I've never heard anyone using 'unsuccess', simply because the term isn't valid. If you want to use the word opposite to 'success' you use the word 'failure'. If you insist on using 'unsuccess', at least find it used in context to make sure you can do so, not just a dictionary entry.

Comment: As @Unreason points out, even though *failure* is overwhelmingly more common, there are over 20,000 written instances in NGrams. Though I doubt you'd find it in any printed dictionaries (certainly none of mine).

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unsuccess?r=66 is based on Random House.

Answer (score 5):

Even though you can find the reference to 'unsuccess' in dictionaries and in various books (see [books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unsuccess%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en)) it does sound rather ugly.

However, as other note, 'failure' is so much more common that it completely overshadows 'unsuccess'.

Side note: on the other hand unsuccessful is a common word, with no synonym with the root fail.

Using unsuccess as a noun might be justified if there are more than two states (success and failure). For example if the context establishes that the result of some action can be success, status quo and failure, then it *might* be justified to use unsuccess.

However, even in those cases it is more clear and sounds more pleasing (to me) to say 'not a success' than to say 'unsuccess'.

If you examine the examples in books you will find it in poems, titles (it is the shorter than 'not a success'), dictionaries and for example as synonym of failure (to avoid repeating a word) and so on i.e. in rare and specific cases.